# Web page not serving in IIS. Took too long to respond

Tags: wordpress, iis

A wordpress site hosted in iis was working fine earlier. Due to maintenance, server been shut down for a week, after restart i tried to backup my wordpress site. Trouble started when i tried to take wordpress backup by browsing into wp-admin page. I couldnt load the wp-admin page since the webpage is not servable by iis. It says site could not be reached. Took too long to respond.

Have tried hosting a new website with hello world html which this works fine. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/279729/web-pages-not-serving-from-iis

Have tried following but same result.

1. Have changed port number.
2. Have stopped the other websites, and browsed the site in iis.
3. Have placed the sample hello world file inside the wordpress and tried to browse.
4. Looked into eventviewer -> Windows logs -> Application. No logs related to iis
5. Looked into %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles logs it shows,

/#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0

/#Version: 1.0

/#Date: 2019-06-12 12:55:53

/#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

2019-06-12 12:55:53 ::1 GET / - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/74.0.3729.169+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 361
2019-06-12 12:55:53 ::1 GET /iisstart.png - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/74.0.3729.169+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/ 200 0 0 4
2019-06-12 12:55:53 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/74.0.3729.169+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/ 404 0 2 4

Clueless to proceed further. Any directions is much appreciated.

Comment: According to current logs, we couldn't find any useful information about your wordpress website. Besides, your logs is related access the localhost:80 site, it is the IIS start page site not wordpress site. I suggest you could post the binding setting about your wordpress site.

Comment: @brando https://imgur.com/7OjEyhH

Comment: The image you have provided is 8080 not 80. So your log is not related with the workpress page. I suggest you could try to enable the FRT to see the details error when you access the workpress admin site. [Details article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).